# React-admin + firebase: element doesn't exist when i click on Edit button

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-admin

i have been facing a problem with React-admin recently. I have created a react-admin panel with Firebase as database. Everything is working (I can create and delete posts), except the fact i can't edit the posts. In fact when i click on the Edit button, a notification pops up on my screen : "**Element doesn't exist**".

```
- "firebase": "^9.0.2",
- "react": "^17.0.2",
- "react-admin": "^3.18.1",
- "react-admin-firebase": "^3.2.24",
- "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
- "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
```

Firebase configuration

```
 import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
    import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
    import 'firebase/compat/auth';
    import {FirebaseAuthProvider,FirebaseDataProvider} from 'react-admin-firebase';
    const config = {
        apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
        authDomain: "XXXXXXXXX",
        databaseURL: "XXXXXXXXX",
        projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXX",
        storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXX",
        messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXX",
      }
    const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config) 
    const options = {
      app: firebaseApp,
      logging: true,
      watch: ['about'],
      dontwatch: ['resume'],
      
    }
    const dataProvider = FirebaseDataProvider(config, options);
    const authProvider = FirebaseAuthProvider(config, options);
    
    export  {dataProvider,authProvider};
```

About component

```
 import * as React from "react";
import RichTextInput from 'ra-input-rich-text';
import {
    Create,SimpleForm,RichTextField,
    ImageInput,ImageField, 
    List,Datagrid,TextField,Edit,
    EditButton,DateField,required,minLength,
} from 'react-admin';

import useStyles from '../useStyles' 
 var validateRich = [required(),minLength(20)]
 const timestamp = Date.now().toString()
 
  export function AboutCreate(props){
    const classes = useStyles();
  
  console.log(timestamp)
  const transform = data => ({
    ...data,
    id: timestamp
}); 
   
   return(
    <Create {...props} className={classes.create} transform={transform}>
    <SimpleForm className={classes.simpleForm} redirect="list" warnWhenUnsavedChanges>
         <div className={classes.div} >English Inputs</div>
        <RichTextInput source="about_english" validate={validateRich}   label="" 
         helperText="Describe yourself." validate={validateRich} />
        <div className={classes.space}> </div>
         <div className={classes.div}>French Inputs</div>
        <RichTextInput source="about_french" validate={validateRich}   label="" 
         helperText="Déecriver vous" validate={validateRich} />
         <div className={classes.space}> </div>
        <ImageInput source="src" accept="image/*.jpg,.jpeg,.png,.jpg" label="" 
              helperText="Select an image" validate={required()} className={classes.imageInput}>
                  <ImageField source="src"  />
        </ImageInput>
     </SimpleForm>
 </Create>
   )
}


export const AboutEdit = (props)=>{
    const classes = useStyles();  
    return(
    <Edit {...props} className={classes.editForm}>
      <SimpleForm className={classes.simpleForm}  warnWhenUnsavedChanges>
         <div className={classes.div} >English Inputs</div>
        <RichTextInput source="about_english" validate={validateRich}   label="" 
         helperText="Describe yourself." validate={validateRich} />
        <div className={classes.space}> </div>

         <div className={classes.div}>French Inputs</div>
        <RichTextInput source="about_french" validate={validateRich}   label="" 
         helperText="Déecriver vous" validate={validateRich} />
         <div className={classes.space}> </div>
        <ImageInput source="src" accept="image/*.jpg,.jpeg,.png,.jpg" label="" 
              helperText="Select an image" validate={required()} className={classes.imageInput}>
                  <ImageField source="src"  />
        </ImageInput>
     </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
    )
}

const date = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10)

const postRowStyle = (record) => ({
  backgroundColor: record.lastupdate > record.createdate ? 'green' : 'green',
  color:'black',
  fontWeight:'bold',
});

export const AboutList = props => {
  
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <List {...props} className={classes.listForm}>
                <Datagrid className={classes.dataGrid} rowStyle={postRowStyle}>
                    <TextField source="id" />
                    <TextField source="about_english"/>
                    <RichTextField source="about_french"/>
                    <DateField source="lastupdate"/>
                    <EditButton className={classes.editButton}/>
                </Datagrid>  
        </List>
    );
}
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import * as React from "react";
import { Admin, Resource} from 'react-admin';
import {dataProvider,authProvider} from './Database/Firebase';
import {AboutList, AboutCreate, AboutEdit} from 
 './Components/About'
import AccountCircle from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';

function App() {
  return (
    <Admin
    authProvider={authProvider}
    dataProvider={dataProvider}>
      {
      <Resource name="about" list={AboutList} create= 
      {AboutCreate} edit={AboutEdit} icon={AccountCircle}/>
    }
    </Admin>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: I just updated the post. Please any solution to resolve this matter?. @FrankvanPuffelen